# Call a async function when a variable is changed (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a `@State` variable and async function. I want to call the async function whenever that variable is changed.

Basically, what I am trying to do

```
        VStack {
            Text("")
        }
        .onChange(of: var) { newValue in
            await asyncFunction()
        }
```

But this gives me the following error

> Cannot pass function of type '(Int) async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly call an async function in the synchronous function. You need to wrap your call in `Task` or else you need to declare your function as `async`. Now in this case you cannot make your `onChange` action `async` so you need to wrap your call with `Task`.

```
Task { 
    await asyncFunction() 
}
```